# Summary conditional sum using dplyr

Tags: r

I would like to create columns based on the State, to count the total count for the year.

```
test <- data.frame(Year=c(rep(2005,3),rep(2006,3),rep(2007,3)), State = rep(c("AK","AZ","CA"),3), count=c(12312,43243,1234,6737,56,123,1,6,8))
```

```
test
  Year State count
1 2005    AK 12312
2 2005    AZ 43243
3 2005    CA  1234
4 2006    AK  6737
5 2006    AZ    56
6 2006    CA   123
7 2007    AK     1
8 2007    AZ     6
9 2007    CA     8
```

Below is my desired output:

```
answer <- data.frame(State=c("AK","AZ","CA"), count2005=c(12312,43243,1234), count2006=c(6737,56,123), count2007=c(1,6,8))
```

```
answer
  State count2005 count2006 count2007
1    AK     12312      6737         1
2    AZ     43243        56         6
3    CA      1234       123         8
```

Comment: Looks like pivot long to wide to me (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html)

Comment: `test %>% pivot_wider(State, names_from = Year, values_from = count)
`

Comment: You can add to the @Maël's answer `names_prefix = "count"` like this: `test %>% pivot_wider(State, names_from = Year, names_prefix = "count", values_from = count)` And you will get the desired column names. Cheers.

Comment: It's confusing that you refer to summarizing and counting data in both the title and text, since the operation you're actually doing is just reshaping, not actually counting anything new

Answer (score 1):

**1) pivot_wider** We can use `pivot_wider` like this

```
library(tidyr)

test %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = count, names_prefix = "count")
## # A tibble: 3 x 4
##   State count2005 count2006 count2007
##   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1 AK        12312      6737         1
## 2 AZ        43243        56         6
## 3 CA         1234       123         8
```

**2) reshape** A base R solution using reshape is

```
reshape(test, dir = "wide", idvar = "State", timevar = "Year")
##   State count.2005 count.2006 count.2007
## 1    AK      12312       6737          1
## 2    AZ      43243         56          6
## 3    CA       1234        123          8
```

**3) xtabs** The question seems to want to label the horizontal axis as `answer` and that can't be done with a data frame.  We can do that with a matrix or table but then we will need to put the states into row names rather than a column.  If the precise names and dimnames are not important then omit the second line.  This also uses only base R.

```
xt <- xtabs(count ~ State + Year, test)
dimnames(xt) <- list(rownames(xt), answer = paste0("count", colnames(xt)))
xt
##     answer
##      count2005 count2006 count2007
##   AK     12312      6737         1
##   AZ     43243        56         6
##   CA      1234       123         8
```

Comment: I think my edit to the question may have been misleading. As far as I know, OP did not want to label the axis answer; I typed `answer` to simulate the print in the console. Sorry for wasting your time.